# colocar pedidos en orden con valor 0.codigo php

Tags: php

Tengo una aplicación que hace lectura de unos datos de unos pedidos. Los pedidos por norma general traen un orden (1,2,3,4,5,6...), pero los que se envían urgente en el mismo día, llegan con orden 0 todos.

Necesito conseguir es colocar esos pedidos nuevos con orden siguiente al último que había.
Por ejemplo, si hay 7 pedidos, el primero que llegue urgente con orden 0, tome el orden 8. El segundo que llegue con roden 0, tome el orden 9 y así.
Os escribo el código que tengo a ver que hay mal:

```
<?php
    ob_start();

      header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');     

    $conexion = new PDO('xxxxx:xxxx=xxxxxxx;dbname=xxxxx','xxxx','xxxxxxxx');
    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT numeroOrden, viaje, ordenviaje FROM orden ORDER BY viaje,ordenviaje");
    $statement->execute();
    if($statement != null) {
      $datos = $statement->fetchAll();            
      if($datos != false) {  
        for ($i=0; $i <= count($datos) - 1; $i++) { 
          if($datos[$i]['viaje'] == 1 && $datos[$i]['ordenviaje'] == 0) {
            $statementAll = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE orden SET ordenviaje = ordenviaje + ? WHERE ordenviaje != ?");
            $statementAll->execute([1, 0]);
            $statementOrder = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE orden SET ordenviaje = ? WHERE numeroOrden = ?");
            $statementOrder->execute([1, $datos[$i]['numeroOrden']]);
          }
        }
      } 
    }

    ob_end_flush();   
?>
```

Comment: No puedes añadir enla consulta de la tabla orden el campo orden en el group by?

Comment: Debes ordenar por órden y por fecha

Comment: el problema no es la fecha, si no que todos los pedidos que entran en el mismo dia van con ordenviaje 0 y necesito colocarles número correlativo para que al ordenador los pedidos como yo quiera no se vuelva loca la aplicación y desordene mi orden.

Comment: @Jakala  está ya insertado               $jsonData = array();        
        $hoy = date('Y-m-d');
        global $conexion;
        $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT numeroOrden, fechaEntrega, poblacion, provincia, status, camion, direccion, nombre, geopos, viaje, ordenviaje FROM orden WHERE camion = ? AND fechaEntrega = ? AND (status = ? OR status = ?) ORDER BY viaje,ordenviaje");
        $statement->execute([$camion,$hoy,"PENDIENTE","ENTREGADO"])

Comment: Pon un pequeño ejemplo de los datos porque no se logra entender ni cómo tienes los datos ni qué es lo que quieres.

Comment: ¿Tienes alguna otra restricción? Por ejemplo, aplicar el orden por fecha o simplemente ir agregando al final.

Comment: @TamaraGívica me referia a que añadieras en la consulta, en la parte de ORDER BY, el campo numeroOrden (entiendo que es tu id de tabla) Primero por viaje, luego por numeroOrden y luego por ordenviaje `order by viaje, numeroOrden, viaje`

Comment: Lo solventé utilizando N + 1 para orden 0, de momento está funcionando.

Comment: Se me plantea otro problema: para copiar los datos a la app utililzo un ejecutable que está continuamente revisando si hay pedidos nuevos o se han eliminado algunos para hacer lo mismo en la aplicación (contando la cantidad de pedidos que hay). El problema que tengo es que al actualizar la app si el ejecutable no ha hecho lectura del pedido 1 al 20, solo hasta el 10, en la app solo me muestra del 1 al 10 y debo dar a un botón refrescar para que aparezcan el resto. ¿De qué manera puedo solventarlo? había pensado en dejar una copia estable de unos 30 segundos de retardo y que haga lectura de eso

Comment: Nadie puede ayudarme? No doy con ello...